# Will firebaseui be made compatible with firebase SDK version 9 soon?

Tags: firebase, firebaseui

I recently refactored my code to the new firebase SDK version 9 only to realize later that  the new SDK is not compatible with firebaseui. Since I rely heavily on firebaseui for authentication of my app's users, I decided to roll back to SDK version 8. I know that there is a compat temporary fix but I don't know how to implement it with firebaseui.

Is firebaseui going to be made compatible with SDK ver. 9 soon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to install the `next` version with:

```
npm i -S firebaseui@next
```

It will take a while until it gets to the "normal" version.

You can read more about it in this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/877).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will definitely try this.

Comment: Seems like it's not possible to use firebaseui@next with the normal v9. Instead, it's necessary to have the v9(compat) version installed. https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/pull/850

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, stumbled upon the same issue right now.

In case anyone encounters this error:

`WARNING in ./node_modules/firebaseui/dist/esm.js 101:378-415 export 'default' (imported as 'firebase') was not found in 'firebase/app' (possible exports: FirebaseError, SDK_VERSION, _DEFAULT_ENTRY_NAME, _addComponent, _addOrOverwriteComponent, _apps, _clearComponents, _components, _getProvider, _registerComponent, _removeServiceInstance, deleteApp, getApp, getApps, initializeApp, onLog, registerVersion, setLogLevel)`

Is directly related to firebaseui 5.0.0 is not compatible with firebase 9.0.2. Going to firebaseui@next fixes this without further issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was troubleshooting this the entire day.

This is what works:

- Ensure firebaseui@next is installed (your version should be ^0.600.0).
- When importing firebaseui and firebase, use:

  ```
    import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
    import * as firebaseui from "firebaseui";
  ```

My issue stemmed from not using:

```
import * as firebaseui from "firebaseui";
```